# How to properly connect an old record player output (spade connector, possibly amplified) to an RCA tape deck with built in amplifier?

Tags: cables, speakers, adapter, rca

I have an old magnavox record console which for some reason the speakers don't seem to get very loud.

Tracing the components, I think I can bypass those built in speakers completely and have the output of the system (spade connectors) go directly into an old tape deck with built in amplifier which has external speakers connected to it.

1. When using an adapter, anything to worry about?
2. How do I know if the signal is amplified?
   Their is a volume knob but it doesn't seem to get very loud. A little less than halfway through turning does it finally start to make sound
3. The wires are connected to internal speakers and internal (I assume) things next to each speaker that I think does bass

The back of the console has the hookups for the internal speakers and hookups for external (all spade connectors screwed into terminals). The internal speakers just seem to share a single ground wire. Is that normal?

Doing a search on the internet for a bit, I couldn't find anything related to this specific model: **1RP621**.

Comment: What's a "horseshoe clip"? Picture or link?

Comment: @brhans I'm guessing spade lugs to fit under screw terminals

Comment: @hobbs Aah ofc - that makes sense.

Comment: search for "spade terminal" to "RCA" adaptor(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important for you to figure out whether the output that you refer to is a line level signal (i.e. just conveys information, not power), or an amplified signal (designed to drive speakers directly). If it's a line level signal, then yes, you can plug that into a tape deck with an amplifier. If it's an amplified/driven signal, you're likely to burn out your tape deck's input.

To figure this out, you should look at the manual if you can find it online. Is that output meant to drive speakers? If so, it's already amplified. It should be passed to speakers, not another amplifier.

As far as what those connectors are called, I'd just call them lugs. To connect RCA cables to it, buy an RCA cable (RCA on both ends), cut it in half and strip the insulation off near where you cut. You now have two RCA to wire "adapters". Use a nut/bolt or similar to attach them to the horseshoes.

Comment: As long as you don't crank the output up to more than a few volts, there's nothing wrong with feeding a speaker output into a line-level input.

Comment: I guess I could measure the voltage at full volume to see how much is coming down through the speakers. What would be too high?